# Dynamics CRM - How to get the Message default display string

Tags: dynamics-crm

Does anyone know how to use C# to get the Default Display String for a Message?

The Default Display String is the first column displayed when you open a Solution, select an Entity (such as Case), and then select Messages.  It contains values like "A Parent Case cannot have more than {0} child cases. Contact your administrator for more details."

The DisplayString Entity seems like the right place, but it only has the CustomDisplayString and the PublishedDisplayString, and not the default display string.  Microsoft have confirmed that the Default Display String is not in the DisplayString Entity, but they don't say where it can be found...

I have tried searching the Metadata Browser, and even went trawling through the Organisation and Config databases, but no luck.

Any help greatly appreciated ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this doesn't answer your question directly, it's a clue.

I checked a bit in the database, then searched for the Account entity message "Existing Account?" in the file system.

It's in this DLL:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Dynamics CRM\CRMWeb\bin\Microsoft.Crm.Application.Components.Strings.dll

[image]

As far as accessing strings in that DLL from C# goes, I'm currently at a loss. You might want to create a MSFT ticket to see if they have any further suggestions. Another thought is that if you're targeting a particular entity, or a few entities, maybe copy the default message to the CustomDisplayString for the messages you're interested in.

Comment: That's as close as I think I will get to a solution.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.